# Does the Frechet Inception Distance (FID) consider color?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network, grayscale

I was wondering if the Frechet inception distance for two colored datasets would be the same than the FID calculated for the same datasets converted to grayscale

Answer (score 0):

No.

FID depends on the feature extractor being used, i.e. inception network. If the feature extractor assigns different features to color and grayscale image, there is no guarantee that it will be same.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. I dont understand the role of color in CNNs. Do you know how what is it role in Inception? I thought that all color information is lost in CNNs, but I am not sure if that is the case.

Comment: CNN doesn't understand colors per se. From a data perspective, colored data and grayscale data comes from two different distributions (domains). This is known as "Domain Shift" problem in machine learning. CNNs naively can't handle domain shift although there is a large literate on it. But from FID calculation, I am not aware of any way you can adopt to new domain with the same CNN backbone.

Comment: @Manveru I feel FID is not the right tool for what you are trying to do.